# Buscar si una hora esta en un pool de horas

Tags: excel

Como puedo saber si una hora esta dentro de un rango de las demas horas. Pongo la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo E2 me debería de regresar un Dentro si B2 esta en el rango de C2:D2, C3:D3, E4:C4 etc o un Fuera si no cumple la condición.

Intenté este código `=IF(AND(B2>=MIN(C2:C16),B2<=MAX(D2:D16)),"YES","NO")` Pero me trae el error `#¿NOMBRE?`

Como podría solucionarlo, bienvenidas sugerencias

Comment: E4:C4 no es un rango válido, por otro lado me parece extraño la especificación "E2 me debería de regresar un Dentro si B2 esta en el rango de C2:D2, C3:D3, E4:C4 etc o un Fuera si no cumple la condición." por favor clarifícala

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene tener rangos solapados? Por ejemplo, las filas 5 y 8 cruzan sus horarios... Como poder, se puede hacer, pero va a hacer que tarde en devolverte el resultado (si esto se replica muchas veces en el mismo archivo, podría tardar minutos en calcularlo)... En cambio, si tuvieras rangos no solapados, ordenados de menor a mayor, sería muchísimo más rápido

Answer (score 1):

Probé la formula en mi Excel y funciona perfectamente, el error debe ser en el nombre de las funciones. Si su Excel esta en Español pruebe:

`=SI(Y(B2>=MIN(C2:C16),B2<=MAX(D2:D16)),"YES","NO")`

Comment: Bueno si, era el problemita que me di cuenta rápido, el problema es que sigue evaluando mal, por ejemplo la fila 7 tiene una hora que no conflictua con otros horarios del pool, pero me evalua TRUE por que también se esta evaluando el mismo, como prevengo que no evalue sus fechas.

Comment: No logro entender ya que al mirar la fila 7 en la foto veo que es para la columna `B7` `06:01:00pm` y esta hora esta en el rango entre `C7` `05:51:00pm` y `D7` `06:11:00pm`.

Comment: Si, la hora es 06:01:00 pm, ni diez minutos antes ni 10 minutos despues en la columnas C y D hay un horario entremedio, es decir, no hay un horario entre las 05:51:00 pm y 06:11:00 pm por lo cual esta es una hora válida. Las demás horas si conflictuan. El problema con lo que hicimos es que, las horas entre las 05:51:00 pm y 06:11:00 pm siempre evaluará TRUE, pues es parte de la misma fila que se esta evaluando (la 7). Lo que quiero es omitirla

Answer (score 0):

Como se mencionó y confirmó en la otra respuesta, uno de los problemas es el idioma que utiliza la instancia de Excel utilizada por el OP.

Una forma de solucionarlo es usar las fórmulas en español. Otra alternativa es instalar el paquete de idioma el cual lo descargas del sitio de Office.

Sin embargo, cambiar el idioma ya sea de la fórmula o de la configuración de Excel no será suficiente para obtener el resultado esperado.

La especificación es

> Por ejemplo E2 me debería de regresar un Dentro si B2 esta en el rango de C2:D2, C3:D3, E4:C4 etc o un Fuera si no cumple la condición

Lamentablemente no está clara.